# How to stop event bubbling of dynamic elements?

Tags: jquery

```
$(".remove_btn").live('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   $(this).parent("td").fadeOut("slow",function(){
     $(this).remove();
   });
});
```

This event fires several times and removes all items. how to stop it. thanks in advance.

Comment: why have you used  $(this).remove(); if don't want to execute it ?

Comment: If you're using `.live()` the event has _already_ bubbled all the way up before jQuery handles it. What do you mean by "all items"?

Comment: there are several buttons with same class.

Comment: Not sure [exactly what effect you are going for](http://jsfiddle.net/xtKBH/) here... Please can you explain the issue a little more... What are the expected results?

Comment: @nnnnn you mean this is not possible?

Comment: It's likely possible to achieve the end result you're after (whatever that is), but perhaps via a different mechanism. Can you provide a demo (perhaps at http://jsfiddle.net) that shows the behaviour you are currently getting, and explain what you would like to happen instead? Or at least show a sample of your html. (Do you have nested elements with that same class?)

Comment: @EjazKarim Slightly off topic, I'm not sure what version of jQuery you're running but `live()` has been deprecated as of 1.7 and has been completely removed in the version 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/live/ Use `on()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".remove_btn").live('click', function(e){
   $(this).parent("td").fadeOut("slow",function(){
     $(this).remove();
   });
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Whey would removing `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` help to _prevent_ bubbling?

Comment: bcoz as we are preventing its default behavior of click once it is clicked, there is not need to use e.stopImmediatePropagation()

Comment: What I mean is that the OP's code _already had_ `e.preventDefault()`. And preventing default behaviour and preventing propagation are not the same thing. So (ignoring for now that you can't stop propagation from a `.live()` handler since the event will have already propagated) removing the one line of the OP's code actually related to bubbling isn't very helpful. (In any case, you should update your answer to provide an explanation of how you think that solves the problem.)